# Adapter Not Attached error in android recycler

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I have defined the separate adapter Class and getter and setters.

Can anyone help to clear the error?

Thanks in Advance.

this is the class which using the recycler view. the separate card view has attached to the Recycler

```
public class boxInService extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    inserviceAdapter inadapter;
    List<serviceData> serviceDataList;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private static final String PREF_NAME="share_pref";
    String op;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_box_in_service);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Boxes in Service");
        serviceDataList=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.in_service_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        pref=getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
        op=pref.getString("operator_stored","");
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        progressDialog.show();

        loadData();

    }

    private void loadData() {

        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                ROOT_URL + boxinService + op,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i=0;i<=jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String chip=object.getString("chip_id");
                                String ua=object.getString("ua_key");
                                String cas=object.getString("cas");
                                String model=object.getString("stb_type");

                                serviceData s_Data=new serviceData(chip,ua,cas,model);
                                serviceDataList.add(s_Data);

                            }

                            inadapter=new inserviceAdapter(boxInService.this,serviceDataList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(inadapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
        );

        VolleyRequest.getInstance(this).addToRequest(request);
    }

}
```

Is anything Missing?

Comment: post your error logs too

Comment: add complete error log